# Wordpress CSS Sidebar code issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is the issue. if you look at the screen shot below. The border of "Live gaming from tekgoblin" is bleeding into the ad code above the border. I am not sure why as it only happens with that part. I have tried and tried to fix this and am looking for others input. Looks fine in IE but not FFox or Chrome.

http://www.tekgoblin.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen-Shot-2012-09-28-at-2.59.18-AM.png

you can look at www.tekgoblin.com and you will see this.

Comment: can u post result images

Comment: This is how it should look http://www.tekgoblin.com/wp-content/uploads/tekgoblinsc.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove to one properties in your css as like this:

```
div.bsap_1250066 a {
    float:left; // remove this line 
}
```

because you have allready define `display:block;`.

Comment: I removed the code off the ad site that controls the css of the ad.

Comment: @Sanity and remove also this div.bsap_1250066 a float:left; remove this css also

Comment: I am trying to remove it from the site and it wont remove, hang on. If I add a float:none; on the custom site CSS would that work? can you still see the float left?

Comment: div.bsap_1250066 a{} remove to float:left; this and div.bsap_1250066{} remove to height this css ................

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure without further study, but your ad doesn't have a height and aslong as its always going to be the same height, you could set the below to fix the problem. If you don't have access to the CSS, then just place it in your local CSS to overwrite, and if that doesn't work assign `!important;` to the height to overwrite the externally imported css creating issues for you.

```
div.bsap_1250066 {
    display: block;
    height: 245px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or you could define a fixed height for your `h4`, achieving the same but not having static ad heights. It really depends on how this effects your site globally, there are many fixes open to you.

Comment: So I tried that and it doesnt seem to have done anything. The ad gets its CSS from another site "display:block;font-size:11px;color:#888;font-family:verdana,sans-serif;margin: 0 0 30px 0;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;overflow:hidden;float:left;"